# .NET TransactionScope on Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, transactionscope, daab

we are using DAAB and TransactionScope on Oracle.
Our application manage all the connection to only 1 database.
This type of implementation it seems to need "Oramts.dll".
Is there a way of using your DAAB and TrasnsactionScope without MTS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.  The DAAB code has a bunch of calls into stuff that is supported in MTS.